# Entity Framework Core - database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following quite complex table structure (names were changed and some fields removed). Originally when adding or updating table1 it added new items into table2, I therefore changed the relationship in table2 from having only one primary key to a combined key to ensure that if an item with `Table1Id` and `Table2Id` exists, it should update it, otherwise insert it. `Table2` has many columns with a `CustomDataType`, which is a link to derived `CustomType` tables that get values added.

I tried various mappings but I either got errors like `Table2Id` with value is already tracked or the error I'm getting now. The relationship is very complex and I have spent hours trying to figure out how to best resolve this but so far nothing seems to work.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here and how to get it right?

Here is again the relationship I'm trying to resolve:

- `Table1` has many `Table2` Items
- `Table2` has many `CustomDataType` items and is linked to `Table1` via `Table1Id`; it also uses `Table1Id` together with `Table2Id` to identify a unique row
- `CustomDataType` has an unique `Id` and three columns: `CustomType1`, `CustomType2` and `CustomType3`
- `CustomType` is the parent of `CustomType1`, `CustomType2` and `CustomType3` and has a unique `Id` and some value columns

Code:

```
    public class table1 : ClientChangeTracker
    {
      [Key]
      public string Table1Id{ get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<table2> Table2List { get; set;}
      //various other fields
    }

    public class table2 : ClientChangeTracker
    {
      public string Table1Id { get; set;}
      public string Table2Id { get; set;}
      public CustomDataType item1 { get; set; }
      public CustomDataType item2 { get; set; }
      //many other CustomDataType fields (about 20)
    }

    public class CustomDataType : ClientChangeTracker
    {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<CustomType1> CustomType1 {get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<CustomType2> CustomType2 { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<CustomType3> CustomType3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomType1 : CustomType
    {
        //left empty to force creating different table for CustomType
    }

    public class CustomType2 : CustomType
    {
         //left empty to force creating different table for CustomType
    }

    public class CustomType3 : CustomType
    {
         //left empty to force creating different table for CustomType
    }

    public class CustomType
    {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public double Value1 { get; set; }
      public double Value2 { get; set; }
    }
```

In the `Context` class I have the following mapping creating a combined key because only `Table1Id` combined with `Table2Id` can yield a unique result:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<table2>()
  .HasKey(x => new {x.Table1Id, x.Table2Id}
```

The data is saved to the database using the following code:

```
 public Entities.Table1 Save(Entities.Table1 table1)
 {
     _context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(table1, e => EntityHelper.ApplyStateUsingIsKeySet(e.Entry));

     if (_context.table1s.Any(x => x.Table1Id == table1.Table1Id))
     {
         LastSaveMode = SaveMode.Update;
         var newTable1 = _context.table1s.Update(table1).Entity;
         NumberOfObjectsWrittenToUnderlyingDatabase = _context.SaveChanges();
         return newTable1;
     }
     else
     {
         LastSaveMode = SaveMode.Add;
         var updatedTable1 = _context.table1s.Add(table1).Entity;
         NumberOfObjectsWrittenToUnderlyingDatabase = _context.SaveChanges();
         return updatedTable1;
     }                                          
 }
```

ApplyStateUsingIsKeySet Code:

```
public class EntityHelper
{
    internal static void ApplyStateUsingIsKeySet(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry.IsKeySet)
        {
            entry.State = ((ClientChangeTracker)entry.Entity).IsDirty ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }
}
```

Tables get created ok in the database however, when running the application, it causes the error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
>   row(s)

Comment: Most likely the problem is caused by the `TrackGraph` and `EntityHelper.ApplyStateUsingIsKeySet` (which btw you forgot to include). Your Table2 has a composite PK with no auto generated values, so it will always be considered with `IsKeySet == true`, hence will be marked for update. But if there is no record in database with such key, the `UPDATE` statement will return 0, hence the exception you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  I added the missing Code for EntityHelper.ApplyStateUsingIsKeySet.  If according to what you say,  IsKeySet is always True, would I have to change ApplyStateUsingIsKeySet to check individual entities and mark the EntityState as Added when IsKeySet is wrongly marked as true?

Comment: I think `IsKeySet` is unreliable for composite PKs. You either need to maintain custom state in your entity which indicates if it's new or existing. The other way is to load the existing collection from the database and detect add/remove/update manually. Eventually you can take a look at [Detached.EntityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#detachedentityframework), but I haven't tried it, so can't share opinion.